# Fixed point system convergence

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I am writing a computer program that solves a fixed-point system and I need to determine the convergence criteria. I am implementing an algorithm from a journal article, and the author states the following:

> ...we suggest to cast [the] system as a fixed-point
> system, u=g(u), with the requirement for convergence being that the
> eigenvalue of $ G = [∂g_i/∂u_j]$ of the largest modulus must satisfy
> $|λ_i|<1$.

The author cites the book *Iterative Solutions of Nonlinear Equations in Several Variables* by Ortega and Rheinboldt.

I am an engineer, not a mathematician, and I am really out of my depth here. I found a copy of the Ortega text, but it's a very dense book and since I don't know what page is being cited it has not been much of a help.

I have the Jacobian and have calculated its eigenvalues.

I am confused  because I have replicated the example the author gives in the paper, and the system takes several iterations to converge - but at each iteration, even the first, $|λ_i|<1$! I am unable to reconcile this with the excerpt from the article I posted above.

I suppose what I am asking is this: is there something special about the largest absolute value of an eigenvalue being less than 1 when solving a fixed point system? I have found several 'oblique' references to this idea, but nothing concrete. It may just be the case that I lack the vocabulary to search properly. Or is it possible that, depending on the application, another convergence criterion may be necessary and that $|λ_i|<1$ does not necessarily guarantee convergence?

In case anyone is curious, the paper is A Note on the Analytical Solution of Cubic Equations of State in Process Simulation by Rosendo Monroy-Loperena, 2012.

Comment: I do not have enough context to give an answer, but some comments: Generally for fixed point systems a condition for convergence is that the map be a contraction, $\|f(x)-f(y\| \le \alpha \|x-y\|$ with $\alpha <1$ being the important point. Without extra conditions I am surprised that the eigenvalues are the characteristing quantities here, I would have expected the matrix norm (or $\max$ singular value) as a characteristic. So, I am obviously missing something.

Comment: According to the author, they have proven that the map is a contraction. I apologize for the lack of context, as I mentioned I am quite ignorant when it comes to linear algebra and it wasn't clear to me exactly how much information to include. In your example, is y the iteration following x?

Comment: No, it is a condition that the fixed point map must satisfy.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I found a corresponding equation in one of the papers proofs.

Comment: The proof of the fixed point theorem is constructive, straightforward. Worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

When you are solving a system of $n$ equations in the form $x = G(x)$, Banach's fixed point theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ states that if $G$ is contractive in some norm (all norms in a finite-dimensional space are equivalent), the fixed point method will converge. When $G$ is differentiable, the contractivity can be analysed in terms of the norm of the Jacobian matrix.

So, why the eigenvalues? When you consider a matrix norm induced by some vector norm, you have that
$$
\|A\| = \sup_{x\ne 0} \dfrac{\|Ax \|}{\|x\|}.
$$

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $v\ne 0$ is an associated eigenvector, you have that $A v = \lambda v$ and so,
$$
\|A\| = \sup_{x\ne 0}\dfrac{\|A x\|}{\|x\|} \ge \dfrac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|} = \dfrac{\|\lambda v\|}{\|v\|} = |\lambda|$$
This way you see that the absolute value of any eigenvalue is a lower bound for any matrix norm. When all eigenvalues are smaller than 1 (in absolute value), there is some matrix norm for which $\|J_G\|<1$ and, as a consequence, the fixed point method will converge.